# CMake with rosserial_arduino tutorial error

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While doing the tutorial, i get the following error when i run catkin_make

*-- ==> add_subdirectory(helloworld)
CMake Error at helloworld/CMakeLists.txt:11 (rosserial_generate_ros_lib):
Unknown CMake command "rosserial_generate_ros_lib".
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Invoking "cmake" failed*

What could be the problem?

I use ubuntu 12.04 with Hydro

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195496/cmake-with-rosserial_arduino-tutorial-error/) by [Robbie025](https://answers.ros.org/users/5911/robbie025/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest you to check whether the content of `ros-hydro-rosserial-arduino` includes `arduino-cmake` files. I believe `rosserial_generate_*` CMake functions for arduino are defined in these files.

If file mentioned in comment is absent, try to add it in the place where CMake can find it. Maybe it will work.

---

Originally posted by [kp](https://answers.ros.org/users/2425/kp/) with karma: 26 on 2014-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kp](https://answers.ros.org/users/2425/kp/) on 2014-10-22**:
Would be helpful if you include link to the exact tutorial with which you have a problem.

**Comment by [kp](https://answers.ros.org/users/2425/kp/) on 2014-10-22**:
https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/blob/indigo-devel/rosserial_client/cmake/rosserial_client-extras.cmake

This file should be present in your system, and CMake should be able to find it.

I tried to find it in hydro-devel branch, but seems it's not there. So maybe tutorial is for Indigo.

**Comment by [pando85](https://answers.ros.org/users/20569/pando85/) on 2014-10-24**:
I tried it in groovey and I coudn't compile it, but with indigo all go well.